# Who framed the org.osgi.framework.* interfaces?

Tags: api, standards, osgi, equinox

I understand that OSGI is just a specification and they don't event mandate that implementation be in Java.

Then who/which guys have framed the "org.osgi.framework.x" packages. For e.g. where does the **BundleContext.java** class come from? Has this API provided by **OSGIALliance** itself?

Note that I understand that the implementation of these interfaces are provided by various different communities. I only need to know where the foundation interfaces come from, as I see both Knopplerfish and Equinox have similar org.osgi.framework.* files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand that OSGI is just a specification and they don't event mandate that implementation be in Java.

Not true:

http://www.osgi.org/About/HomePage

> The OSGi Alliance is a worldwide consortium of technology innovators that advances a proven and mature process to create open specifications that enable the modular assembly of software built with **Java technology**.
>
> Then who/which guys have framed the "org.osgi.framework.x" packages.

The OSGi Alliance is a consortium, and the framework API was arrived at by consensus.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to skaffman's answer: Please have a look at the FAQ posted on the OSGi Alliance's web side ( http://www.osgi.org/About/FAQ ). You'll find good descriptions about the work, the specification process and relationships to other standard bodies.

The foundation interfaces can be downloaded here: http://www.osgi.org/Specifications/HomePage . You have to choose the release and accept the click-trough license.

Answer (score 1):

The org.osgi.* packages are part of the OSGi Specification. They can be downloaded as a JAR from the following page: http://www.osgi.org/Specifications/HomePage